# Javascript method like isFocused()?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any function or variable where I can get wheter the document is focused at the moment?

Comment: For a filed or for document

Comment: Hint: [PageVisibility API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/). There's a good article on html5rocks.